# How to set dark mode for NSToolbar in macOS Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, uikit, mac-catalyst, ios-darkmode, nstoolbar

In my iOS/macOS app the user can choose between a light and a dark appearance.

This is done by setting the overrideUserInterfaceStyle of the app window, for example

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

It works fine on iOS/iPadOS.

On macOS (Catalyst) the app uses an NSToolbar, which always appears in the mode chosen in the system settings, regardless what ist set for the overrideUserInterfaceStyle of the window (see screenshot).

Since this is not a good visual impression, I would like to know how I can set light/dark mode for the NSToolbar too.

[image: app in dark mode with NSToolbar in light mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding an macOS plugin which has access to the whole AppKit API. Instructions can be found here:
[How to Access the AppKit API from Mac Catalyst Apps](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-access-the-appkit-api-from-mac-catalyst-apps-2184527020b5)

Then you can set the desired appearance there at runtime, for example:

```
NSApplication.shared.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
```

Comment: While Dynamic can be great for other things, "darkAqua" is not available in Catalyst.

Comment: Yes, darkAqua is not available in Catalyst, but that's why we use the macOS plugin which uses pure AppKit instead of Catalyst. For me, this works as written here. Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

Add `UIUserInterfaceStyle` with a value `Dark` to your app’s Info.plist. That will force the whole app to dark mode on iOS 13+ and Mac Catalyst (you won’t need to set overrideUserInterfaceStyle).

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiuserinterfacestyle

Comment: Thank you for this.  Saved me a ton of time.

Comment: mr. original username.  MARK THIS ANSWER CORRECT!

Comment: Thank you, this is a valuable hint, but does not completely solve the problem, since it is a "static" solution and does not allow to change the appearance at runtime. Please see the accepted answer.

Comment: @iosdeveloper You are correct, though I ran into a handful of weird bugs when using the NSApplication method (I don’t recall specifics, but basically there were a few toolbar buttons and menus that would fail to switch styles). But if it works for you, great!